# same method, Different output.The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

My route is correctly configured, and my methods have the decorated tag.
Method "GetMessage" work fine but "DeleteAllLoc" return "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.".
They are the same...What is problem?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Loc")]
public class LocController : ApiController
{       
    [Route("DeleteAllLoc")]
    public string DeleteAllLoc()
    {
        return "OK";
    }
    [Route("GetMessage")]
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "Hello";   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorate your `DeleteAllLoc` method with the `[HttpGet]` attribute to specify that it's a `GET` request - I think it's inferring it as a `DELETE` because of the method name.

Comment: I Add [HttpGet] attribute and problem solved. thanks

Comment: This is not a good solution for something that is not a real problem. As a start I recommend reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api - it will help you to get some basic understanding of the "issue". Also http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html will help to  undertand the use of the different http verbs.